# Parsing an xml in python to find xpaths of all elements (nodes)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have an xml file-
https://github.com/schogini/jVoiD/blob/master/Modules/jVoidCustomers/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml

I am using the following code to parse a xml file-

```
 from lxml import etree
 xslt_root = etree.parse("/Users/cbuser1/CodeBlueFabricator/src/poc/PythonParser/mvc-config.xml")
 print(xslt_root)
```

I get the result of my program as-

```
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x10e95bcc8>
```

Now I need to loop through this object and get the xpath of every element in it. (every single element inside the xml file). Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to show code that you have written to try solve this problem.

Comment: food for thought. actually, i dont see any methods in lxml module that can give you xpath of an element but you can build xpath yourself, given that XML are usually very ordered. This can be done. I have a code to do that, but its not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was able to find a solution. I converted my XML file to JSON using this-

```
import json
import xmltodict
with open("INSERT XML FILE LOCATION HERE", 'r') as f:
    xmlInString = f.read()
print("The xml file read-")
print(xmlInString)
JsonedXML = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xmlString), indent=4)
print("\nJSON format of read xml file-")
print(JsonedXML)
with open("myJson.json", 'w') as f:
    f.write(JsonedXML)
```

And then I went through the json and found all the innermost nodes and saved their key and value in a txt file using this-

```
import json

data = json.load(open('GIVE LOCATION OF THE CONVERTED JSON HERE'))
token_key_value_dictionary=[]
only_tokens_dictionary=[]
uniqueKey ='xml'
def recursive_json_parser(start_point_value,uniqueKey,start_point_key=''):
    if start_point_key !='':
        uniqueKey += '.'+start_point_key
    if type(start_point_value) is str or type(start_point_value) is unicode:
        token_key_value_dictionary.append([str(uniqueKey),str(start_point_value)])
        only_tokens_dictionary.append(str(start_point_value))
        uniqueKey =''
    elif type(start_point_value) is list:
        for i in start_point_value:
            recursive_json_parser(i,uniqueKey)
    else:
        for key,value in start_point_value.items():
            recursive_json_parser(value,uniqueKey,key)

for key,value in data.items():
    print (len(value))
    recursive_json_parser(value,uniqueKey,key)

f = open('tokens.txt','w')
for row in only_tokens_dictionary:
    print (row)
    if row!='':
        f.write(row+'\n')
f.close()
```

In the 2nd program, I went through the json-consisting of lists, and dictionaries to reach in to the innermost nodes consisting only of a key and a value and no more list or dictionary inside it.